# Show that a matrix A above the R field is congruent to itself squared iff A is non-negative

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, matrix-congruences

How do I show that a symmetric matrix A above the R field is congruent to itself squared iff A is non-negative, but I'm not sure if by non negative the author meant positive semi-definite:

$$\exists P: P^tA^2P=A \iff \forall x: x^tAx\:\ge 0$$

or just non-negative:

$$\exists P: P^tA^2P=A \iff A \ge 0$$

i.e, for each element in the matrix it's positive.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to start by figuring out what the question means.

Let's see:  $$A = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 1\cr}$$ is positive semidefinite but not elementwise positive, and $$A^2 =  \pmatrix{2 & -2\cr -2 & 2} = P^T A P$$
where $$ P = \pmatrix{\sqrt{2} & 0 \cr 0 & \sqrt{2}}$$
so it must be that positive semidefinite was meant.

Hint: [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: hm ... thinking about the hint, still don't have an idea how to approach to it.

Comment: Can you please detail the solution sketch?

Comment: $A$ is positive semidefinite iff all its eigenvalues are nonnegative.  The eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$.  So how do the numbers of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues of $A^2$ compare to those of $A$?